# Is there a way to get *activities overview* on ubuntu while using i3?

Tags: i3-wm, activities-overview

I'm using i3-wm as it's very convenient in general, once you get ahead of the initial learning curve. I miss the activity overview tho, since it allows you to *loosely* look for applications, files,... that is without being too specific with the name. Is there a way to launch it in i3 (with a standard config file)?

I couldn't find anything specific on google

Thank you very much